# XDebug with eclipse luna freezes at 57 %

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I have a problem with xDebug running on eclipse.

This is my php.ini xDebug configuration:

```
[XDebug]
 zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.6-vc11.dll"
 xdebug.remote_enable = On
 xdebug.remote_host = "localhost:8080"
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
 xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
 xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

The run configuration works fine, but when i try to debug, it shows:

```
Launcing <debug configurazion name> : (57%)
```

And in the internal web browser it shows me an empty page.

How can i salve the issue???

Thanks in avance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, i solved in this way:

First i changed the file windows>system32>drivers>etc>hosts and added the line

```
127.0.0.1 local.test.it
```

secondly, i changed the configuration of the server configuration at windows>preferences>php>debug.
then go to server settings area and click "php servers">new and do the following changes:
Name: server name

Debugger: XDebug

Base URL: local.test.it:your_port.

now it works fine.

I hope it would be helpful to someone...